# Соединение между двумя компьютерами через сокет python?

Tags: python, сокет, twisted

Попытки реализовать p2p-сеть.
Есть 2 компьютера, выходящие в сеть через роутер, например. И есть сервер с белым ip.
Компьютеры открывают одно соединение на прослушку (5005 и 5006 порт, например), а вторым соединением соединяются с сервером.
Сервер получает Hello сообщения от компьютеров и запоминает адрес и порт отправителя, допустим это (ip-addr port:39392 и ip-addr port:21213).
 Потом рассылает всем известным ему пирам эту информацию.
И вот когда с первого компьютера, я пытаюсь подключиться ко второму компу используя полученные ip и порт, то никакой реакции. 
Каковы пути решения?

Comment: Настроить NAT в роутерах на обоих компах и купить белые IP для тех же обоих компов?

Comment: Такой подход понятен, но если разрабатывается для массового использования? 
Если ли какие-то пути обхода программно, используя python?

Comment: Делать прокси-сервер (SOCKS5, STUN/TURN и прочие ключевые слова для гугла)

Comment: Но чем моя реализация, отличается от того же STUN/TURN версии?
Знаю, что STUN работает с UDP и если я использую UDP, то связь идет.
TURN для tcp, но как понимаю, приницп действия там схожий

Comment: Возможно, и ничем, но я про то, что через сервер нужно пускать ВЕСЬ трафик, а не только ip-порт передавать. Если оба компа с серыми IP за NAT, прямую связь между ними вы не установите никак

Comment: (Хотя есть ещё udp hole punching, но это для гуру и работает далеко не всегда, можете не надеяться осилить это)

Comment: Но используя UDP с STUN все идет. Связь есть. TCP вот не в какую

Comment: Не знаю, каким именно образом в вас UDP работает, но вот TCP-соединение за серыми IP вы не установите абсолютно точно, только через прокси

Comment: Или же TCP-велосипед поверх UDP :)

Comment: Если с Вашей точки зрения, использование UDP намного хуже в таком роде сети, нежели TCP?
Понимаю, что в UDP данные могут теряться, а кроме?

Comment: У меня нет никакой точки зрения, я просто сообщаю вам, что UDP обходить NAT с горем пополам может, а TCP не может. Или используйте UDP (раз вы говорите, что у вас уже работает), или делайте полноценный прокси, третьего не дано